# How do I use an array in a whiptail menu?

Tags: arrays, bash, syntax, whiptail

Trying to write a simple script, on a Linux machine with systemd, to display a list of time zones using an array in whiptail. So far:

```
tzones=$(timedatectl list-timezones)
arr=( $tzones )
count=0
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do allzones[$count]=$(echo "\"$i\""); ((count=count+1)); done
for i in "${allzones[@]}"; do echo $i; done #So I know I have a list of items in quotes at this point
whiptail --title "Time zone" --menu "Select time zone" 25 78 16 "${allzones[@]}"
```

Bash keeps spitting out a help menu for whiptail. I've only just started messing with whiptail and I've been at this script a while so not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Btw. : Add a valid shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement all the recommendations made there.

Comment: Never worked with whiptail, but according to the man-page, after the menu-height (16) must come a list of _tag and item_ **pairs**. The first character of a tag must be a unique **letter** (so the man-page says), but in the way you create the array items, the first character of a tag will be a double quote. In addition, since you need a list of pairs, the number of elements in `allzones` must be an even number. Not sure that this condition is fulfilled in your case. BTW, since you are fiddling (unnecessarily?)  with `echo`, I would also display the array elements with `xxdump`.

Comment: BTW, [this example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail#Menus)  seems to confirm what I suspected in my comment, only that in this example, the first character in a tag can also be a `<`, which is clearly not a letter either. I don't know whether other special characters are allowed as well.

Comment: @user1934428 In what man page did you find that "The first character of a tag must be a unique letter"? The man page available to my instance (v0.52) only states that a "first letter" would act "as a hot-key", thus pressing a letter would move the selection to an item starting with that letter. But as for providing a dataset of tag and item pairs, neither does a tag's first character **have to** be a letter (non-letters just don't act as hot-keys), nor does it have to be **unique** (pressing the letter multiple times actually cycles through all of the matching items).

Comment: @pmf : I concluded from the "first letter is hotkey",  that it must be a **letter**, and that it must be a unique one. I did not know that you can cycle through it, and that tags starting with a non-letters simply don't have a "hot key" property, The tag therefore can be any string. So the only requirment is that there are pairs, i.e. that the number of array elements is even. Right?

Comment: @user1934428 I haven't used whiptail either (before answering this Q) but as it asks for providing a set of tag and item pairs, adding up the amount of tags and the amount of items provided is definitely even (and if you were to collect both of them in an array, also the amount of items in that array would be even). Note, however, that either one can be hidden in display using the `--notags` and `--noitem` flags, respectively (yet, it's always the tag that gets output if the user selects an item), so the amount of "things" shown is not necessarily even.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to use consecutive numbers as tags. You could use `cat -n` on the list of timezones to prepend each line with a number. As timezones do not contain spaces, there's no need for using arrays or to further take care about spacing.

```bash
list=$(timedatectl list-timezones | cat -n)
whiptail --title "Time zone" --menu "Select time zone" 25 78 16 $list
```

The menu will look something like this:

```
─────────┤ Time zone ├────────

Select time zone

    1   Africa/Abidjan
    2   Africa/Accra
    3   Africa/Addis_Ababa
    4   Africa/Algiers
    :   :
```

Comment: pmf: Thank you! I had forgotten that each menu item needs to have two entries. I was trying to figure out how to get that into the array when I saw your answer, which is perfect. (I upvoted it but apparently you can't upvote an answer to your own post if you're new here.)